# XMPP, <message failed="1">

Tags: xmpp

I'm using `psi` to connect to an xmpp server at `chrome.pl`. I was talking, when suddenly my messages started instantly coming back from my server xmpp address. The typical exchange looks like this (this is from `psi` XML console):

My message:

```
<message type="chat" to="…@jabbim.pl/…" id="accfa">
<body>nie wiem</body>
<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
</message>
```

Server response:

```
<message type="chat" id="accfa" to="…@jabbim.pl/…" failed="1">
<body>nie wiem</body>
<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
</message>
```

I cannot find anything regarding this `failed="1"` in any XMPP specification. What's that?

Comment: That looks indeed like a non-specified behavior. You should contact the admins of `chrome.pl` and tell them that their service is sending non-defined attributes in stanzas in error situations.

Answer (score 1):

As @Flow said in his comment, that isn't a valid attribute for a message stanza (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#appendix-A.5). From the looks of it, the server should be returning a message stanza with the 'type' attribute set to "error", and a relevant <error/> element (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-8.3.3 for a list of conditions).